# laravel Show old post data once validation is failed

Tags: laravel, forms, validation

I am trying to update a post and for that I have form with following markup

```html
<form method="post" action="{{ admin_url('services/'.$service->id) }}">
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Service Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name"
            value="{{ old('name') ? old('name') : $service->name }}">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Initially when form opens it should show model value that is {{$service->name}} and once form is submitted and if validation fails it must show old input

The problem is when input is blank, the logic `{{ old('name') ? old('name') : $service->name }}`
 evaluates to false and `$service->name` is displayed instead of empty value.

My controller code

```php
public function update($id, Request $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|max:255|min:5'
    ]);
    $service = Service::find($id);
    $service->name = $request->input('name');
    $service->save();
    return redirect(admin_url('services'))->with('message', 'Service updated successfully');
}
```

Comment: Try `{{ old('name', $service->name) }}`

Comment: When your validation fails, what is your statement in controller that redirects back to form? Please add your controller code.

Comment: Hi Digvijay, i have added my controller code, can you please help me out

Comment: @user3209130 can you try `Validator::make()` method because of it has that method `fails()`

Comment: @user3209130 Has my code solved your problem?

Comment: Yes it solved the issue

Comment: @user3209130 I added a answer with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Validator::make()` method

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
     'name' => 'required|min:2|max:255'
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
} else {
    return redirect(admin_url('services'))->with('message', 'Service updated successfully');
}
```

Comment: Didn't work either,

I think when validation is called on request object laravel automatically fires
Redirect::back()->withErrors($validation)->withInput();
base on https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/requests#old-input

Comment: @user3209130 Above logic not working right? check any error that occurs.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a default value to the [old](https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers#method-old) function that will be used if there is no value with that name in the session.

Replacing

```
{{ old('name') ? old('name') : $service->name }}
```

with

```
{{ old('name', $service->name) }}
```

Should solve your issue.

Complete code:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ admin_url('services/'.$service->id) }}">
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Service Name</label>
        <input type="text"
               class="form-control"
               id="name"
               name="name"
               value="{{ old('name', $service->name) }}">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
```

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
     'name' => 'required|min:2|max:255'
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect()->route('your_route')->withInput(['name'=>$request->name])->withErrors($validator,'validation');
} else {
    return redirect(admin_url('services'))->with('message', 'Service updated successfully');
}
```